# Loading JS functions on dynamically loaded pages

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am using CSS-Tricks dynamic page script found here.

http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        /*
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                        */
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Body

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

I am using a number generating script (below) on one of my pages, but I am having trouble getting it to only show on one, single page. When placed in the head of the document or my includes/scripts.php that is loaded on every page, it shows on every page. When only included on the page I want, it does not work.

```
<script>

function counter() {
var num = 0;
    for (num = 0; num < 500; num++) { 
      document.write(num + ' &nbsp; ');      
    }
}
counter();

</script>
```

I have tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to only appear on a single page. Is there any way around this without ditching the CSS-Tricks Dynamic Page?

Comment: Please add more code showing exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

What if you insert your code into dynamicpage.js like this?

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if(newHash === 'somePage') { // the page you want to implement the effect
      // your code
    }
    /*
      ....
    */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a class to your `<body>` tag (or other near-to-top level wrapper if you're just dynamically loading to the HTML attribute of your body tag in the first place) that lets the script distinguish between pages that ought to use the function and those that don't, something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(`body.usesCounter`).on(eventToBeCounted, counterFuncAsCallback);
    }
```

But the fact that it's not working when only loaded on a single page does suggest you've got something else going on. Can you give us the header for the single page, the script block (and where it is on the page), and some sense of how/when it's called?

Are you loading the single page dynamically? If you are, the script tags won't be accessible unless you reload the DOM somehow or else do some funky binding via jQuery's `$.on()` or something similar that listens for changes to the DOM.

---

### UPDATE

Looking at the tutorial you are trying to emulate, the general problem you're facing is that the JS on that page you're loading isn't going to be registered with the DOM. I've had to write code that can read dynamically lodaded JS like this, and if  you want to do it both effectively and securely, it's quite a lot of effort. The point of JS-based page loading is to be fetching "view-like" content; assets, html, etc.. In a single-page environment, any required logic should—generally—exist *on that page*.

I highly recommend you include the code in your initial page, and then conditionally call it when the appropriate page arrives. There are lots and lots of ways to do that, basically find some distinguishing feature of the page(s) where your counter should be run, and, *after* having loaded the page, look for said features and, if found, allow your code to run. You might have something as simple as a variable, `isCounterPage` set, by default, to false. Then, after a dynamic page load occurs, if the inspection fires and this var remains false, don't execute code associated with the counter. Otherwise, let it do its thing.